# Image/Face Morph application that uses reference points

Tags: windows

I'm looking for an image morphing application that uses points and (presumably) automatic triangulation to morph an image into another. Reason is stuff like Photoshop's mesh grid or liquify require way too much work to set up correctly, whereas with this method I can only add points where it's needed in the source and destination images and automatically increase the quality.

[image: morph example]

(example source: https://steven.codes/blog/face-morphing/)